# android how to set Error image using Aquery library

Tags: android, gridview, imagedownload, aquery

I have a custom Gridview. In my adapter asynchronous image downloading done using AQuery. images are downloaded properly but in some cases error will occur so that time imageView background goes totaly white.i want to set that error image.

Now here is the code of my adapter in gridView():

```
try{
            String[] tmp_arr_thumb_img = prodItems.get(holder.position).getprod_image().split(global.split_seprator);
            //String imageID = tmp_arr_thumb_img[0];
            String thumbImg = tmp_arr_thumb_img[1];

            if (aQuery.shouldDelay(holder.position, convertView, parent, global.GLOBAL_UPLOADED_PHOTOS_URL + thumbImg)){
                aQuery.id(holder.imageView).image(R.drawable.no_image);
            }else{
                aQuery.id(holder.imageView)
                        .image(global.GLOBAL_UPLOADED_PHOTOS_URL + thumbImg,true,true,200,0, new BitmapAjaxCallback(){
                            @Override
                            protected void callback(String url, ImageView iv, Bitmap bm, AjaxStatus status) {

                                iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
                            }
                        }.animation(AQuery.FADE_IN));
            }
        }catch (OutOfMemoryError err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code with this wil use a place holder imaage

```
aQuery.id(holder.imageView)
                    .image(global.GLOBAL_UPLOADED_PHOTOS_URL + thumbImg,true,true,200,R.drawable.placeholder, new BitmapAjaxCallback(){
                        @Override
                        protected void callback(String url, ImageView iv, Bitmap bm, AjaxStatus status) {

                            iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
                        }
                    }.animation(AQuery.FADE_IN));
```

Comment: this type of image constructor not available so it gives me error on that line.

Comment: and if i add bitmap as 2nd last parameter then u does not callback method.

Answer (score 0):

If we are not able to load the image, use a default image (R.drawable.default_image)

```
String imageUrl = "http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/vikispot/android-w.png";
aq.id(R.id.image1).image(imageUrl, true, true, 0, R.drawable.default_image);
```

Make image view "invisible" if image failed to load

```
imageUrl = "http://a.b.com/invalid.jpg"; 
aq.id(R.id.image1).image(imageUrl, true, true, 0, AQuery.INVISIBLE);
```

Make image view "gone" if image failed to load

```
aq.id(R.id.image1).image(imageUrl, true, true, 0, AQuery.GONE);
```

Comment: but how to detect image loading failure??